# SQLlite - how to get max count value from each group

Tags: sqlite, group-by, count, max, greatest-n-per-group

This question has been asked before, but in different formats and so I cannot apply the answers to my problem (this may also be due to my inexperience with SQL).

My table is from a soccer database. The aim is to discover which month (from each year) holds the most matches.

Below returns the month, year, and number of matches(played). I want to get the Max value of matches per month group (within the year group).

```
select strftime('%m',Match.date) as "Month", strftime('%Y',Match.date) as 
"Year", count(*) 
from Match
group by 2,1
order by 2 asc, 1 asc, 3 desc;
```

Please give a detailed explanation as to your approach, not just the code so that I can learn. Thank you :)

Sample data:

```
league_id, season, stage, **date**, match_api_id, home_team_api_id, away_team_api_id, home_team_goal, away_team_goal

1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-17 00:00:00** 492473 9987 9993 1 1
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-16 00:00:00** 492474 10000 9994 0 0
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-16 00:00:00** 492475 9984 8635 0 3
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-17 00:00:00** 492476 9991 9998 5 0
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-16 00:00:00** 492477 7947 9985 1 3
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-09-24 00:00:00** 492478 8203 8342 1 1
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-16 00:00:00** 492479 9999 8571 2 2
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-16 00:00:00** 492480 4049 9996 1 2
1   2008/2009   1   **2008-08-16 00:00:00** 492481 10001 9986 1 0
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us sample data.

Comment: And what is the expected output from this data?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am looking for the maximum matches per month per year.
So, I split the date of the match into year and month, and then grouped them.
How do I retrieve the max number per group?